# Template parsing error: template: :2: unclosed action

Tags: windows, shell, docker

I'm trying to run that script via Docker on Windows

```
$(docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.${NETWORK}.IPAddress }}" ${NAME})
```

I'm and getting the error:

```
Template parsing error: template: :2: unclosed action
```

After a quick search I have only found a reference for `template : 1`  about changing the quotes, but that does not work for me.

I am using windows 10.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to replace the variables by actual values and "debug" in that way what goes wrong?

Comment: Yeap , i have printed succesfully the above lines of the script and replaced the current variables with them .

Comment: And only with the variables you get this error?

Comment: Well , the "NETWORK" variable returns two names of networks something like "network1 network2" , I suppose that format causes the conflict . If i try with one of these separately its working fine but the code was supposed to work as it was .

Comment: Ok, "who" is telling it's supposed to work as it was? Maybe you ask this source for further information? If you can refer to a website, please add this link as well! Could you also clarify if you do DOS or Powershell scripts?